# Why can't turtle draw a kite properly?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I've been trying to draw a kite shape with particular dimensions but the ending point won't connect with the starting point.

[Kite reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yp6vj.png)

Here is my code

```
from turtle import *

top_vertice = 80 # degrees
middle_vertice = 119 # degrees
bottom_vertice = 42 # degrees
kite_short_side = 85
kite_long_side = 158

SOUTH = 270


fillcolor('red')
begin_fill()
setheading(SOUTH + (top_vertice // 2))
forward(kite_short_side)
right(180-middle_vertice)
forward(kite_long_side)
right(180-bottom_vertice)
forward(kite_long_side)
right(180-middle_vertice)
forward(kite_short_side)
end_fill()
```

I've also tried the opposite direction i.e. setheading(SOUTH + (top_vertice // 2)), left instead of right but the result was the same.
Anyone know why this is and how to fix it?

Thanks

**Edit**
[Here's the outcome.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTlsG.png)
I've added dots to the starting and ending points to better indicate the problem. You can also see that it looks slightly asymmetrical, so that means either my angles off or turtle can't draw kites.

Comment: Could you share the result you are getting and point out the error?

Comment: I've updated the question to include the result

Answer (score 0):

```
from turtle import *

top_vertice = 80  # degrees
middle_vertice = 119  # degrees
bottom_vertice = 42  # degrees
kite_short_side = 85
kite_long_side = 158

SOUTH = 270

fillcolor('red')
begin_fill()
setheading(SOUTH + (top_vertice // 2))
forward(kite_short_side)
right(180 - top_vertice)
forward(kite_long_side)
right(180 - bottom_vertice)
forward(kite_long_side)
right(180 - top_vertice)
forward(kite_short_side)
end_fill()

done()
```

The key change is to use the **top_vertice** angle instead of **middle_vertice** for the second and fourth turns. The sum of angles around each vertex should add up to 360 degrees to ensure the turtle returns to the starting point.  I've added the **done()** function at the end to keep the window open after drawing the shape.

Comment: I'm sorry but that's not the same shape I'm trying to achieve.
Thanks for trying

Comment: `from turtle import *` should not be used, as it dumps 150+ functions into the namespace, leading to variable clashes and confusions between instance mode and functional mode. Only import the functions you need, or use instance mode to avoid pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is your "Kite reference" is incorrect.  If we check it against [a kite calculator](https://www.1728.org/quadkite.htm), we find with top angle 80, middle angle 119 and a short side of 85 pixels, as shown, then the long side has to be 152.46 pixels.  Correct the code for that:

```
import turtle

SOUTH = 270

top_vertice = 80  # degrees
middle_vertice = 119
bottom_vertice = 42

kite_short_side = 85  # pixels
kite_long_side = 152.46 # was 158

turtle.fillcolor('red')

turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.setheading(SOUTH + top_vertice/2)
turtle.forward(kite_short_side)
turtle.right(180 - middle_vertice)
turtle.forward(kite_long_side)
turtle.right(180 - bottom_vertice)
turtle.forward(kite_long_side)
turtle.right(180 - middle_vertice)
turtle.forward(kite_short_side)
turtle.end_fill()

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.done()
```

and we get:

[image]